# prevent glitches from ionic loading screen

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, web, mobile

I have an ionic v4 application that I want to "secure" with a pin code every time the user starts the application. I've managed to set up most of the behavior (`platform.ready`, `platform.resume`) as I want but I have a slight glitch when the first time the application loads you can briefly see the protected page.

Ideally what I want to flow to be is that if the user is starting the app for the first time he/she is guided through steps of setting up the environment. So I'm using `Storage` to determine if certain information is present and then `navigateForward` to move to the screens with steps.

The problem I have with this approach is that initially when ionic loads (i think before `platform.ready` is called) it already loads the default webpage- so you briefly get to see the protected webpage while ionic is still initializing.

Can anybody give me some recommendations about how I could fix this problem? I'm quite new to ionic and angular itself.

Comment: I would not make the protected page the default. Use a different page on load (e.g. your configuration steps page) and then navigate to the protected page if the user is allowed to.

Comment: If I show the configuration page, the root of the problem still occurs, it would show the configuration page before it would transists to the login page right?

Comment: Yes, but you could also show a different page so the "glitch" is less noticeable. You could also [manually hide the splash screen](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/#splashscreenhide) after navigating to the correct page.